# splitting a column up into separate columns based on a third column

Tags: r

I've got a problem with my dataframe. I want to add an Article column because the ItemType column is a combination of article_id's and payment_id's.

I've written some code so you can replicate.

```
JLID <- c(1:9)
JLID <- as.data.frame(JLID)
JHID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
JLID$JHID <- JHID
ItemType <- c("PLU", "PLU", "PAY", "PAY", "PLU", "PLU", "PAY", "PLU", "PAY")
JLID$ItemType <-ItemType
Itemiden <- c(37, 235, 1, 1, 35, 6, 1, 1, 1)
JLID$Itemiden <- Itemiden
quant <- c(3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1)
JLID$quant <-quant
```

If you add this to the code you get what I want the data to look like.
Based on if the ItemType is PLU.

```
Art <- c(37, 235, "", "", 35, 6, "", 1, "")
JLID$Art <- Art
```

Splitting the whole column `Itemiden` is also a option but must also be based on `ItemType` because as you can see some  `Itemiden` could be payment or article.

My thoughts were something like this cause I have to do this on a large dataset.

```
JLID [(JL$ItemType %in% "PLU"), "Art"] <- "JLID $Itemiden"
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `ifelse(JLID$ItemType == 'PLU', JLID$Itemiden, "")`

Comment: @bouncyball While `ifelse()` is a viable solution in this case, it might cause issues with certain data types, e.g., `Date` or `POSIXct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the Q could be misleading as `split()` is the name of a base function in R. The OP wants to add a column to a data.frame which is filled with values of a second column depending on a condition in a third column.

#### Create new column based on condition in another column

In base R, I suggest to use the `replace()` function

```
JLID$Art <- replace(JLID$Itemiden, JLID$ItemType != "PLU", "")

JLID
#  ID JHID ItemType Itemiden quant Art
#1  1    1      PLU       37     3  37
#2  2    1      PLU      235     2 235
#3  3    1      PAY        1     1    
#4  4    1      PAY        1     1    
#5  5    2      PLU       35     1  35
#6  6    2      PLU        6     4   6
#7  7    2      PAY        1     1    
#8  8    3      PLU        1     6   1
#9  9    3      PAY        1     1
```

Alternatives are subsetting

```
# copy whole column
JLID$Art <- JLID$Itemiden
# replace unwanted elements on condition
JLID$Art[JLID$ItemType != "PLU"] <- ""
```

or `ifelse()` as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928630/splitting-a-column-up-into-separate-columns-based-on-a-third-column#comment72954798_42928630)

```
JLID$Art <- ifelse(JLID$ItemType == "PLU", JLID$Itemiden, "")
# or
JLID$Art <- ifelse(JLID$ItemType != "PLU", "", JLID$Itemiden)
```

But note that the documention of `?ifelse` warns

> The mode of the result may depend on the value of `test` (see the examples), and the class attribute (see `oldClass`) of the result is taken from `test` and may be inappropriate for the values selected from `yes` and `no`.

#### Where `ifelse()` fails

While in this case `ifelse()` is a viable solution, it doesn't always works as expected with other data types, e.g., `Data` or `POSIXct`. I've spent hours on debugging because of this *"feature"*. An example:

```
JLID$PayDate <- ifelse(JLID$ItemType != "PLU", as.Date("2017-04-15"), NA)
JLID
#  ID JHID ItemType Itemiden quant Art PayDate
#1  1    1      PLU       37     3  37      NA
#2  2    1      PLU      235     2 235      NA
#3  3    1      PAY        1     1       17271
#4  4    1      PAY        1     1       17271
#5  5    2      PLU       35     1  35      NA
#6  6    2      PLU        6     4   6      NA
#7  7    2      PAY        1     1       17271
#8  8    3      PLU        1     6   1      NA
#9  9    3      PAY        1     1       17271
```

Here, the class has been stripped off and the dates appear as numeric.

`replace()` or subsetting are more reliable:

```
JLID$PayDate <- replace(rep(as.Date("2017-04-15"), nrow(JLID)), JLID$ItemType == "PLU", NA)
JLID
#  ID JHID ItemType Itemiden quant Art    PayDate
#1  1    1      PLU       37     3  37       <NA>
#2  2    1      PLU      235     2 235       <NA>
#3  3    1      PAY        1     1     2017-04-15
#4  4    1      PAY        1     1     2017-04-15
#5  5    2      PLU       35     1  35       <NA>
#6  6    2      PLU        6     4   6       <NA>
#7  7    2      PAY        1     1     2017-04-15
#8  8    3      PLU        1     6   1       <NA>
#9  9    3      PAY        1     1     2017-04-15
```

#### Create data frame

The OP has chosen to create the data.frame in a way which might cause problems. Namely, it contains a column `JLID` which has the same name as the data.frame itself. This ambiguity may cause unexpected results or errors (Just happend to me!).

In base R, I recommend to set up a data frame manually either

```
JLID <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:9),
  JHID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  ItemType = c("PLU", "PLU", "PAY", "PAY", "PLU", "PLU", "PAY", "PLU", "PAY"),
  Itemiden = c(37, 235, 1, 1, 35, 6, 1, 1, 1),
  quant = c(3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

str(JLID)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ ID      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# $ JHID    : num  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
# $ ItemType: chr  "PLU" "PLU" "PAY" "PAY" ...
# $ Itemiden: num  37 235 1 1 35 6 1 1 1
# $ quant   : num  3 2 1 1 1 4 1 6 1
```

or, if the columns are existing already for some reason

```
ID <- c(1:9)
JHID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)JLID$JHID <- JHID
ItemType <- c("PLU", "PLU", "PAY", "PAY", "PLU", "PLU", "PAY", "PLU", "PAY")
Itemiden <- c(37, 235, 1, 1, 35, 6, 1, 1, 1)
quant <- c(3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1)
JLID <- data.frame(ID, JHID, ItemType, Itemiden, quant, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note, that `data.frame()` requires to explicitely state that character values *must not* be coerced to factor to be in line with the OP's sample data.